# How to get SMS as send method in the Messaging&Notification module (D7)?

Tags: 7, views

I cannot find anything for D7, only D6.
Anyone knows howto?
Alternatively; any way to send SMS via views-send-module?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [SMS Framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/smsframework) for D7 ,, built a sub-module for my SMS Getway provider (it might be already there for your case),, and with my custom module controlled the rest in notifying|messaging ,,, etc

> The SMS Framework is set of modules that enables interaction between
>   mobile users and Drupal using SMS. Several popular SMS gateways are
>   supported and the included API allows developers to add support for
>   additional gateways. The API also allows other modules to implement
>   SMS features.

Comment: I also use the SMS framework for D7, but the problem is, I can't find any way to actually make and send SMS'es, except from "Sent to phone" in the SMS Framework.
In the Messaging&Notification module there are 3 send methods; plain mail, html-mail and message on screen, but the SMS message method is missing (though it's described to be there, but just in the D6 version).
Hope you understand what I miss.